# DataTokens on SignalR OwinRoute

Tags: asp.net, signalr, token, routes, owin

In signalr 2.0 the hub route ca be defined with RouteCollectionExtensions.MapOwinPath:

```
var routeBase = myAreaRegistrationContext.Routes.MapOwinPath(
    "signalr.hubs", 
    "/signalr", 
    map => { map.RunSignalR(); });
```

However OwinRoute extends RouteBase and there is no DataTokens hash available. Is there any other possibility of setting DataTokens for the signalr route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution for adding DataTokens on the signalr route is to use MapOwinRoute:

```
var routeBase = context.Routes.MapOwinRoute(
    "signalr.hubs", 
    "signalr/{*action}", 
    map => { map.RunSignalR(); });
```

and assign any tokens to routeBase.